# boost deadline_timer cancels pending async operations

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, timer

Clarification needed on this.

Does this mean that any pending operations on the same io_service object will be canceled? If so, how does one go about using an io_service object with multiple sockets. I've got an application with multiple sockets, any number of which may have a pending async read. If I want to use a timer on one socket during an ssl handshake operation it would cancel all pending reads... How is this situation handled?

Comment: "boost deadline_timer cancels pending async operations" - why do you think this?

Comment: Do you mean `deadline_timer::cancel()` member function? It cancels only the timer-related async operations (issued with `async_wait`).

Comment: This is what the boost docs say: This function sets the expiry time. Any pending asynchronous wait operations will be cancelled. The handler for each cancelled operation will be invoked with the boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deadline_timer::expires_from_now()` only cancels [pending operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/expires_from_now/overload2.html) for that particular object, not for all async operations using that `io_service`.

Comment: @Ken next time, at least be specific about _what line_ and _what documentation page_ told you this. I knew the quote from experience, but people shouldn't have to search for it. It's _your_ question. You have to make it work.